# What is the meaning of sentence using Would have? Translate Sentence in Hindi or Marathi

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

What is the meaning of below sentence using Would have?

> Unfortunately, It didn’t happen as i *would have hoped.*

Is writer wanted to say?

> Unfortunately, It didn’t happen as *he had hoped.*

What if he written?

> Unfortunately, It didn't happen as I *had hoped*."

Appreciate if anybody translates it into my regional language (Hindi Or Marathi). I am from INDIA

Comment: I seriously doubt that English-Hindi translations are on-topic on this site. If they are, I don't see why this exact same question could not appear for translations into Dutch, Swahili, Greek and Latin. I think the best answer is the one that does not provide a translation. The answers with translations are mostly, if not completely, useless for anyone who wants to learn English but happens not to understand Hindi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the following sentences

तू माझ्याशी असा वागशील असं मला कधीही वाटलं नाही.
I never hoped that you would treat me like this.

तू माझ्याशी असा वागशील असं मला कधीही वाटलं नव्हतं.
I had never hoped that you would treat me like this.

तू माझ्याशी असा वागशील असं मला स्वप्नातसुद्धा कधी वाटलं नव्हतं.
I had never hoped in my wildest dreams that you would treat me like this.

तू माझ्याशी असा वागशील असं मला कधीही वाटलं नसतं.
I would have never hoped you would treat me like this.

तू माझ्याशी असा वागशील असं मला स्वप्नातसुद्धा कधी वाटलं नसतं.
I would have never hoped in my wildest dreams that you would treat me like this.

Your example

मला वाटलं तसं झालं नाही.
It didn't happen as I hoped.

मला वाटलं होतं तसं झालं नाही.
It didnt happen as I had hoped.

मला वाटलं होईल तसं झालं नाही.
It didn't happen as I would have hoped.

मला वाटलं होतं होईल तसं झालं नाही.
It didn't happen as i would have had hoped.

मला वाटलं होतं होईल तेवढं प्रॉफीट नाही झालं आम्हाला.
We didn't make as much profit as I would have had hoped.

Answer (score 7):

> Unfortunately, it didn’t happen as i **would have hoped.**

The meaning is that during the time of the event the writer wasn't aware of the event, or wasn't interested in it enough to harbor any hopes for its conclusion:

> I've just returned from a long trip, and discovered that my husband had planted a tree in our backyard! Unfortunately, it didn't happen as I **would have hoped**. He planted an apple-tree. I **would have chosen** a walnut tree.

Here, the author had not been planning for the planting of a tree. She discovered it suddenly. Thus, she cannot say "as I had hoped".

Contrast:

> I've just returned from a long trip, and found that my husband had planted a tree in our backyard, *just as we had planned* before I went away! Unfortunately, it didn't happen as I **had hoped.** He planted an apple-tree. I **had hoped** for a walnut tree.

Answer (score 0):

Before the event took place the writer did not know that it was going to happen. Now, when he sees the event taken place, he thinks now that if he had known that the event was going to take place (i.e. before it took place) then he would have wanted it to happen in a way different from the way it happened now.

Answer (score -1):

Aw! I could come up with the translation in Hindi

> बदक़िस्मती से वोह नहीं हुआ जो मैं सोचता के होना चाहिए

Check out CopperKettle's example.

> जब में घर वापस आई तोह मैंने देखा के मेरे पति ने एक पेड़ बो दिया था! बदक़िस्मती से वोह नहीं हुआ जो मैं सोचता के होना चाहिए! उन्होंने सेब का पेड़ बोया, पर मैं अखरोट बोती।